# How do I get pyspark working in Jupyter Notebook in a virtual environment on Windows?

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm receiving the dreaded 'Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number' error but I've followed everything I can find already and it's still not working. The worst thing is I swear this set up worked last week and somehow doesn't anymore.

I can run pyspark perfectly fine in the virtual env from the command line and outside of the virutal environment (I'm using Pipenv) so it must be something to do with Jupyter Notebook. Has anyone solved this problem on Windows who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a fix from [here](https://changhsinlee.com/install-pyspark-windows-jupyter/). My JAVA, SPARK_HOME, and HADOOP_HOME environment variables were configured properly but I added

PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON = jupyter
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS = notebook

and it's working for now.

Comment: Adding those 2 user environment variables worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Set JAVA_HOME environment variable in your python script:

`os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = '/path/to/your/java/exe/'`

If that doesn't work, try setting PATH too:

`os.environ["PATH"] = os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] + "/bin:" + os.environ["PATH"]`

Comment: My Java env variables are all configured correctly, sadly, so it must be something else. Thanks.