# Unable to start a Spark Session in Jupyter notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

First, this is not a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64825755/cannot-create-a-spark-session-in-the-jupyter-notebook) . I just installed pyspark in windows, set up SPARK_HOME variable and ran findspark.init() to make sure there is no installation issue.

running the pyspark shell, the spark (SparkSession) variable is created automatically and things work fine but when I wwant to start a spark session from Jupyter, then I get the following error

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-39c4e6ac7c9b> in <module>
      3 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
      4 
----> 5 spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
      6 

c:\users\ahg01\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py in getOrCreate(self)
    184                             sparkConf.set(key, value)
    185                         # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
--> 186                         sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
    187                     # Do not update `SparkConf` for existing `SparkContext`, as it's shared
    188                     # by all sessions.

c:\users\ahg01\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py in getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    374         with SparkContext._lock:
    375             if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 376                 SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    377             return SparkContext._active_spark_context
    378 

c:\users\ahg01\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    131                 " is not allowed as it is a security risk.")
    132 
--> 133         SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    134         try:
    135             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,

c:\users\ahg01\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py in _ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway, conf)
    323         with SparkContext._lock:
    324             if not SparkContext._gateway:
--> 325                 SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
    326                 SparkContext._jvm = SparkContext._gateway.jvm
    327 

c:\users\ahg01\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\java_gateway.py in launch_gateway(conf, popen_kwargs)
    103 
    104             if not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
--> 105                 raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
    106 
    107             with open(conn_info_file, "rb") as info:

Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

There is no existing SparkContext running, why am I getting this message? There is no predefined spark or sc variable, so I am not sure how to debug this issue

Comment: please show the complete traceback

Comment: Just added the traceback

Comment: specify java_home environment variable

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65129742/how-do-i-get-pyspark-working-in-jupyter-notebook-in-a-virtual-environment-on-win/

Comment: I did set JAVA_HOME but still get the same message. How come pyspark shell is able to initiate a spark session, but I cant?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Test')
```

Comment: Why should it work? Not that i am questioning you, but an explanation about this "Magic line" would surely help an average reader like me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Interesting .. somehow this worked for me.. No idea why though.

Comment: for me it says AttributeError: 'Builder' object has no attribute 'read', the spark object is unusable